# How to rewrite this, so that it doesn't trigger a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is that on pageload a checkbox is triggered and because of this an ajax call is made which makes my page load very slowly.

I have located the code that triggers these checkboxes:

**My jQuery script**

```
$('.checkGroup > input[type="checkbox"]').live('change',function(){
    $t = $(this);
    $t.closest('.checkGroup').find('.payload').toggle( $t.is(':checked'));
    if( !$t.is(':checked') ){
       $t.closest('.checkGroup').find('.payload input[type="checkbox"]')
           .attr('checked',false);
    }
}).trigger('change');


$('.checkGroup input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
   $c = $(this);
   $c.closest('.checkGroup').find('label > span b')
             .text( $c.closest('.checkGroup')
                         .find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length
             );
}).trigger('change');
```

**How can I disable this onload or any other way?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `.trigger('change')` since it triggers the event for the very same functions you are showing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to trigger the `change` after some delay on page load if it is required or else do not trigger it.

```
$(function(){

var $checkboxes =  $$('.checkGroup > input[type="checkbox"]').live('change',function(){
    $t = $(this);
    $t.closest('.checkGroup').find('.payload').toggle( $t.is(':checked'));
    if( !$t.is(':checked') ){
       $t.closest('.checkGroup').find('.payload input[type="checkbox"]')
           .attr('checked',false);
    }
});

setTimeout(function(){
    $checkboxes.change();
}, 500);


});
```